# Form in JavaScript with lockalstorage doesnt do anythig beside whats is default in FF

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
(document).ready(function()
{
    function init()
    {
        $("form input.stored").each(function () 
        {
            var form = $(this).parent();
            var idOfForm = form.attr("id");
            var type = $(this).data("type");
            
            if(localStorage.getItem("#"+idOfForm+" input[data-type='"+type+"']"))
                $(this).val(localStorage.getItem("#"+idOfForm+" input[data-type='"+type+"']"));
 
        });
        
        $("form input[type='submit']").click(function (evt) 
        {
            evt.preventDefault();
            
            
            $("input.stored", evt.target.parentNode).each(function () 
            {
                var form = $(this).parent();
                var idOfForm = form.attr("id");
                var type = $(this).data("type");
                
                localStorage.removeItem("#"+idOfForm+" input[data-type='"+type+"']");
                $("#"+idOfForm+" input[data-type='"+type+"']").val("");
                
            });
        });
    }
    
    
    $("input.stored").keyup(function()
    {
        var form = $(this).parent();
        var idOfForm = form.attr("id");
        var type = $(this).data("type");
        
        //alert("#" +idOfForm+ " input[data-type='" + type + "']");
        
        localStorage.setItem("#"+idOfForm+" input[data-type='"+type+"']",$(this).val());
        
        
    });
});
```

I was working on local storge form but something isnt wright and it doesnt save my inputs beside of what is default in ff, rest is just normal. I have no clue whats it on here, every seams to good.

Comment: Do you ever call `init()`? Any errors in dev tools console?

Comment: yes , i didnt called init()

Comment: now everything works fine :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

and html

```html
   </head>
    <body>
      
        
        <form id="AG">
            Imię: <input class="contact_input stored" data-type="name" type="text"></br>
            Email: <input class="contact_input stored" data-type="email" type="text"></br>
            Telefon: <input class="contact_input stored" data-type="tel" type="text"></br>
            <input type="submit"></br>
        </form>
        
        <form id="AB">
            Imię: <input class="contact_input stored" data-type="name" type="text"></br>
            Email: <input class="contact_input stored" data-type="email" type="text"></br>
            Telefon: <input class="contact_input stored" data-type="tel" type="text"></br>
            <input type="submit"></br>
        </form>
```

Imię: 
            Email: 
            Telefon: 
            
        
        
        
            Imię: 
            Email: 
            Telefon: